# Simple HTTP proxy / routing for my docker containers?

Tags: docker

One of the cool things about docker is that it makes it really easy to spin up different web-apps to test them out.

So I'm soon going to run a few (maybe ~10) containers on one host and I need an easy way to reach them.

Anyone know a *simple* way to route to may different containers, based on subdomain or url?

It should:

- Run in a container itself (not on the host)
- Be dead simple
- Function as automatically as possible (would be nice if you could name a container foo.bar.com and have the traffic sent to it automatically, for example =)
- Easy to automate from within the containers

Anyone know of something simple like this? Hipache seems a little overkill and too much work for my use.

(I'm now making a simple wrapper around nginx, but I don't want to waste my time on that if something already exists..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try [openresty](http://openresty.org/) an nginx lua based distribution that allows you to route all your requests dynamically coupled with a redis database. This way you can create new routes without impacts on actual connections. See [DynamicRoutingBasedOnRedis](http://openresty.org/#DynamicRoutingBasedOnRedis) sample on the site.

You can do more as you script everything with Lua plus the stability of nginx.

For the same price you have load balancing, for a route you can add many hosts.

Answer (score 1):

If hipache seems like too much work, you could try [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy). It seems like it wouldn't bee too much trouble to create a standalone node.js app that does what you describe using this module.  You could run this inside a docker container just like any other node.js app.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's very easy to use.. do you know if it can load new routes without dropping connections?

Comment: Not sure about that, but I just wrote a blog post about using hipache with Docker containers that you might be interested in: http://required.io/hipache-etcd

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own automated http proxy that listens to Docker events and updates routing rules accordingly?

I wrote a simple tutorial on how to do it with Node.js https://memz.co/api-gateway-microservices-docker-node-js/.

Otherwise, you can use [VulcanD](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailgun/vulcand/) from **mailgun** which is quite popular, although it does seem kinda abandoned.